# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore key value keeps coming back

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to migrate some data away from iCloud, so I figured I would simply delete the key once I saved it in the new location then I would know if the value no longer needed migration if the value was no longer in iCloud.

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.removeObject(forKey: objectKey)
```

After I remove that, if I check , the key is empty:

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.object(forKey: objectKey) == nil
```

All good, but when I close and reopen the app, the key has the original value in it before I removed it.  I even tried running synchronize after removeObject():

```
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.default.synchronize()
```

But no good, the key's value keeps returning after I restart the app.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct steps in `removeObject` and `synchronize`. The trick is to wait for some time, I've had to wait up to a few minutes.

Comment: Yeah, we identified that icloud was not the correct tool for what we wanted to do because of the timing issues.

Comment: I can second this, it can sometime take a few seconds or even longer for NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore to sync, and I noticed a lot of issues where updating a value and then building the app again would retain the old value. iCloud is a mess. What did you end up using instead @CharlieOder?